# Examples of other thinkers supporting Lakatos' view of mathematics

Tags: foundations, philosophy

I have recently discovered that the Hungarian philosopher Imre Lakatos, famous for his view on the philsophy of science, also presented some interesting views on mathematics. According to his Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imre_Lakatos#Philosophy_of_mathematics), he believed the mathematical community to possess an almost dialectic ability to assess the validity of proofs and "therefore, he fundamentally disagreed with the "formalist" conception of proof prevailed in Frege's and Russell's logicism,". It goes on to say that his views were frowned upon by his contemporaries. It made me think about this article from Quanta Magazine: https://www.quantamagazine.org/why-the-proof-of-fermats-last-theorem-doesnt-need-to-be-enhanced-20190603/, about mathematicians scrutinizing Wiles' proof of Fermat's Last Theorem. In the article, they claim that "In philosophy of mathematics it’s customary to treat a published proof as an approximation of an ideal formalized proof, capable in principle of being verified by a computer applying the rules of the formal system." It therefore seems that Lakatos' views were discarded for good.

My question is if anyone here knows about any other philosophers or thinkers interested in the philosophy of mathematics who have shared Lakatos' views or something similar. I *do not* intend to start a debate about his views. I simply want to see if others have shared Lakatos' views since I personally do not know of any such thinker, and if so, maybe get som recommandations about interesting reading material on the topic.

Comment: It's rare for people to disagree with the formalist view in writing these days. I do note that often, formal mathematics deals with definitions that have been technically adjusted precisely for purposes of avoiding argument that might invite a criticism of the strict formalist view. We often formulate our definitions (usually making them more capacious) so that they can accommodate whatever we might want to argue about, even if they do not fully resemble the original idea - perhaps sacrificing some intuition in the process. Apparently the ancient Greeks called this "saving the phenomenon."

Comment: @leslietownes " formal mathematics deals with definitions that have been technically adjusted precisely for purposes of avoiding argument that might invite a criticism of the strict formalist view" I'm not sure what you mean here, can you give an example?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was thinking along the lines of the fact that the "point at infinity" in projective geometry (or the "line at infinity") is not a point in the usual sense but is deemed such so that projective transformations map points to "points" and lines to lines. The phenomenon is more important than points being points. And once you've got it, it's very useful even if it seems to the uninitiated like an excess of abstraction or formalism.

Comment: It seems to me that whether other thinkers "have shared Lakatos' views or something similar" is more of an opinionated topic than I'd care to address.  While the perspective of some mathematicians can be pigeonholed with citations into [four schools](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/), this doesn't seem to me an exercise in reasoned mathematical argument (unlike, for example, mathematical logic or meta-mathematics).

Comment: Thank you for the link. It was both interesting and enlightening. If you are concerned with the openness of the phrase «or something similar», rest assured that this is rather an attempt to include views that might disagree with Lakatos on certain particulars but share the basic idea, than an opinionated lack of precision, not willfully anyhow.

Comment: Some aspects of the "dialectic" critique of mathematics are (to me) unobjectionable; working mathematicians proceed from an intuition informed by empirical evidence to formulate theories.  Kurt Gödel was a proponent of mathematical intuition as a concrete faculty, and as juxtaposing that view with profound accomplishment in symbolic logic, has often been [a case study](https://www.jstor.org/stable/420946?seq=1).